# Trying to combine the txt file and Regex

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

i want to know whether it's possible or not to combine regular expressions with a `.txt` file. for example, I want the output to be car.com when I print the file.

[Inside the .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6054R.png)

I tried to implement it inside my Jupyter Notebook to test it out

```
Abused = open("dictionaries/Abused.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
for line in Abused:
Abused_Result = re.search(r"Car", line)
print(Abused_Result.group())
```

But it resulted with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. i'm still learning on using Regex so please correct me if i'm wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Your regex search searches for "Car" in the line. Since your file does not contain any occurence of "Car" it won't find any and therefor be None. Maybe you can explain a little bit further what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ohhh, I thought the line was meant for the text file. If I want to output a word from the the .txt file what regex should i give then?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a use case for regex. regex is for searching specific text patterns in a given string. If you just want the text of the line 'for line in file.readlines()' should do the job. 'line' in this context already is the text from the file.

Comment: sorry if I didn't made it clearer, right now there are 2 txt file that I want to combine and make it into 1 sentences so it could generate random sentences. for example i want the final result to be carsomething.com. but i want to see whether regex would output the first file first before i combine with the 2nd text.

Comment: That really sounds like you shouldn't use regex. regex really is only for searching for specific patterns in strings. E.g. if you'd say you only wanted to get the lines from the file that start with a 'c', contain at least 2 words and are ending with 'com', then you'd use a regex to filter out such lines. If you only want to combine different lines without considering their content, regex does nothing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your RegEx string at e.g. https://regex101.com/

Your current RegEx string will only match the exact character sequence "Car" and hence nothing from the file, resulting in the `NoneType` output of `re.search`.

I'm not sure you want to use RegEx here. My understanding is that you want to do:

```py
with open("dictionaries/Abused.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    Abused = f.readlines()
    for line in Abused:
        print(f"car.{line}")
```

Comment: okay my mistake, if i want the regex to output the words from the .txt file how should i type it? should i type it like this (r'\w', line) ?

Comment: I think `line` is already the words from the .txt file. 
So just `print(line)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "car" in your text file so regex can't find it. For that you got the 'NoneType'

Tell me specifically what do you want?

If you want to print "car.com" if there is ".com" in the file then do this -

```
with open("dictionaries/Abused.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    Abused = f.readlines()

for line in Abused:
    if "com" in line:
        print("car.com")
```

And if you want to know the line index the inside the if statement of the for loop add these two lines (Know that these two will remove the lines from the list not from the text)-

```
print(f"Line number: {Abused.index(line)}")
Abused.pop(Abused.index(line))
```